# paintComponent code not working

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent

I am new to Swing and trying to add a background of an image to my `JFrame`. However my `paintComponent` method is not working. Could you please give me some suggestions on how to fix my code so the image is painted in the background?

Code is below:

```
// all necessary imports have been added.
public class Menu extends JFrame  {
private Image backgroundImage;
private JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Menu window = new Menu();
    window.frame.setVisible(true);
}

public Menu() throws IOException {
    initialize();
}

public void initialize() throws IOException {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 312, 294);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) throws IOException {
    backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("P:\\Profiles\\workspace\\Games\\Images\\matrix.jpg"));
    g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding `paintComponent` of a `JFrame` is not useful, override the `paintComponent` of its content pane instead.

Extending `JFrame` is usually also not necessary.

Finally, it would better to use `initialize` to load the image (rather than loading it at each paint call) and do stuff on the content panel if you need.

Putting it all together, see this example :

```
public class Menu extends JPanel {

    private Image backgroundImage;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(menu);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 312, 294);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Menu() throws IOException {
        initialize();
    }

    public void initialize() throws IOException {

        backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File("P:\\Profiles\\workspace\\Games\\Images\\matrix.jpg"));

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for you help. It now seems to be working. For future reference could you explain why before it was not working as I am still new and don't want to make this mistake again.

Comment: `JFrame` uses a `JPanel` as its content panel. There is no use to override paint methods from `JFrame` , because what you actually see is the content panel of the frame (it is in front and hides everything you attempt to paint directly to this frame) , so this is the component where you want to customize the painting.

Comment: *"Overriding paintComponent of a JFrame is not useful"* - Actually, it's impossible

Comment: `super(g)` should be `super.paintComponent(g)`. You should be using `EventQueue.invokeLater` to launch the program; better to override `getPreferredSize` to of the `Menu` class so that it's hard for the panel to be re-sized beyond the size of the background image